# What is gatsbyContentfulFluid?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, gatsby, contentful

I'm learning Gatsby and GraphQL as a newbie and following this article
https://ibaslogic.com/gatsby-with-contentful-cms/

It has this code:

```
export const query = graphql`
  query($slug: String!) {
    contentfulBlogPost(slug: { eq: $slug }) {
      title
      publishedDate(formatString: "Do MMMM, YYYY")
      featuredImage {
        fluid(maxWidth: 750) {
          ...GatsbyContentfulFluid
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

I'm getting everything but not getting .`..GatsbyContentfulFluid` on my GraphQL query server.
C
an someone please explain what `...GatsbyContentfulFluid` is?
Why we are using it with a spread operator?
and did I miss something while creating Contentful data that's why I'm not getting `...GatsbyContentfulFluid` in my GQL query playground?

Comment: this is the article im following https://ibaslogic.com/gatsby-with-contentful-cms/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a spread operator like we know it in JavaScript, in GraphQL stands for a query fragment.

A fragment's a way of querying a set of fields using reusable units. From [GraphQL docs](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#fragments):

> Let's say we had a relatively complicated page in our app, which lets
> us look at two heroes side by side, along with their friends. You can
> imagine that such a query could quickly get complicated, because we
> would need to repeat the fields at least once - one for each side of
> the comparison.
>
> That's why GraphQL includes reusable units called fragments. Fragments
> let you construct sets of fields, and then include them in queries
> where you need to. Here's an example of how you could solve the above
> situation using fragments:

In your case, the fragment is provided by [`gatsby-source-contentful`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-source-contentful/) and basically, is querying a fluid asset from Contentful, as you do normally when using [`gatsby-image`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-image/#fragments) for local files.

In other words, with `...GatsbyContentfulFluid` fragment you are fetching the mandatory fields from Contentful assets that allow you to use a `gatsby-image` within the asset.

Fragments are not available in the GraphQL playground due to a limitation of the GraphiQL:

> Note, due to a limitation of GraphiQL, you can not currently use these
> fragments in the GraphiQL IDE.

So, you can use fragments (indeed, you should) but you will need to check your fetched data in your code (via `console.logs` or via debug breakpoints) directly since they are not available in the GraphQL playground.

Comment: thanks ferran for reply can you answer one more thing plz?
what is the difference when we use graphql() as a function call and graphql`` with tickback?

Comment: It's the same, but the first one will be deprecated soon.